# AngularJS input pushed to controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been busy trying AngularJS and ran into a little problem. I'll display my App.js and my Index.html below.

Index.html

```
 <ion-tab title="Home">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Overzicht</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="info in inkomsten">
          {{info.name }} <p class="float-left">{{info.value}}</p>
         </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="info in uitgiften">
          {{info.name }} <p class="float-left">{{info.value}}</p>
         </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="info in tabel">
          {{info.name }} <p class="float-left">{{info.value}}</p>
         </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
         <form novalidate>
         <input ng-model="name">
         <input ng-model="value">

         <input type="submit" ng-click="submitForm(name,value)" value="Click me!">

         </form>



     </ion-content>



</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Toevoegen">
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Settings">
</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>


</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.inkomsten= [
{ name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
{ name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
{ name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
{ name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
];
$scope.uitgiften= [
{   name: 'eten',value:'120'},
{ name: 'kat',value:'230'},
{ name: 'schildpad', value: '300'},
{ name: 'huur', value: '200'}
];


}
});
```

I would like to have 2 buttons on my Index.html whom will give the user an option to submit a new entry in the ng-repeat list. 
so naturally these inputs will consist of either "inkomsten" or "uitgaven" . After choosing between these the user can fill in the name of the new input and then the value binded to it. Now, I am not sure how to get the information over to the app.js!

I hope you understand my problem.

Thanks in advance

---

13:20 07-12-2015

After help it now looks like this

app.js

```
  .controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inkomsten= [
  { name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
  { name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
  { name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
  { name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
  ];
  $scope.uitgiften= [
  { name: 'eten',value:'120'},
  { name: 'kat',value:'230'},
  { name: 'schildpad', value: '300'},
  { name: 'huur', value: '200'}
  ];

$scope.addToNgRepeat = function(data) {
  if(data === "uitgaven"){
      $scope.uitgiften.push({name: $scope.name,value:     $scope.value});
   } else {
   $scope.inkomsten.push({name: $scope.name,value: $scope.value});

  }
}
});
```

index.html

```
       <form novalidate>
      <input ng-model="name">
      <input ng-model="value">
      <input type="button" ng-click="addToNgRepeat("addToNgRepeat("uitgaven")")" value="uitgaven">
      <input type="button" ng-click="addToNgRepeat("addToNgRepeat("inkomsten")")" value="inkomsten">
         </form>
```

It doesn't work yet, what am I doing wrong now ? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `$scope.name` and `$scope.value` to access these input because `ng-model` has bind it's value to your scope.
You need 2 button sharing the same click function with different parameter to indicate which button had clicked such as:

`<button ng-click="todofunc(1)" >
<button ng-click="todofunc(2)" >`

```
$scope.todofunc = function(index) {
   if (index === 1) {
      $scope.inkomsten.push({
         name: $scope.name,
         value: $scope.value,
      })
   } else {
      //...
   }
}
```

Comment: But how to make sure it gets added in the appropiate value? "inkomsten" or "uitgiften".. and would I add     $scope.name and     $scope.value in the submitForm()?

Comment: you can pass a parameter to your submitForm() like my example

Comment: 1. ng-click="addToNgRepeat('uitgaven')"

Comment: 2.if(data === 'uitgaven'){...}

Comment: $scope.inkomsten.push ({name: $scope.name,value: $scope.value});

Comment: I've adjusted it and it still doesn't do anything. Could it be that the function input is wrong ? (the if(data === 'uitgaven') ).. that it doesn't register that data is the input of the function?

Comment: Well, it seems to clash somewhere. Doesn't work either way for me! Thank you for your time and effort :) really appreciated

Comment: Apparently using Ionic frameworksand everything, It didn't really like using value and name on the bits of             <input ng-model="name">
         <input ng-model="value">   After changing this, It works.. kinda :) but without your help I wouldn't have figured it out. You cleaned up my code and made it work in theory :)

Answer (score 0):

```
addToNgRepeat("addToNgRepeat("uitgaven")")"
```

should be ...

```
addToNgRepeat("uitgaven")
```